# Azure blob CacheControl is not applied

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have created a new blob and specified CacheControl equal to `max-age=31536000, must-revalidate` (I checked it out in Azure Portal). Now when my blob is loaded by the browser, I see the following:

```
Status Code:304 The condition specified using HTTP conditional header(s) is not met.
Cache-Control:max-age=0
```

I'm concerned about Cache-Control. Why doesn't it represent the value I specified? Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

the 304 error means "not modified" which signals that the blob was cached at the client!  This is the expected behavior.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/25528.azure-blob-storage-and-effective-use-of-cache-control-property.aspx